# iOS Facebook SDK batch requests, single completion block

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

The [iOS Batch Request Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/batch-requests-ios-sdk/#step3) only shows how to execute multiple requests simultaneously and handle their outputs separately. However, I want to make 3 Facebook batch requests simultaneously, and then receive the results of all three in one completion block once all three have completed, so I can aggregate and sort them. Is this possible?

All help is greatly appreciated and I always accept an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method worked for me.  Here's an example of how to do it requesting the user's info, and the user's friends that use your app.  This will return to a single block, and you can parse the result and handle everything at once:

```
NSArray *requests = @[@{@"method":@"GET",
                        @"relative_url":@"me"},
                      @{@"method":@"GET",
                        @"relative_url":@"me/friends"}];
NSError *encodingError;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:requests options:0 error:&encodingError];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"batch":jsonString};

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@""
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog([error description], nil);
                          }
                          else {
                              NSLog(@"Return Data: %@", [result description]);
                          }
                      }];
```

Comment: While uploading a Video to Facebook we include Video Data too. How would that be converted to JSON ?

Comment: Code no longer works, not sure if it is because FBRequestConnection is deprecated or that requests to @"" no longer work..